# MaterialDesign Switch styling not working and squeezing

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design

I have added a switch in my android app and it's using Material Design. I followed their guidelines and also a bunch of example but every single time, it's kind of shrinking. I force a `60dp` width and `32dp` height and I can clearly see that the `60dp` is not respected but the height is.

And it's also looking as below:

[image]

But I am trying to get something like this: This is `checked = false` status, for the `checked = true`, I just change the background to green.

[image]

I do not understand why the thumb is also as big as the track when I set as well both height.

Below is my layout:

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/switchLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="90dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/settingsSwitch"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/settingsSwitch"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/switchSettingsName"
                android:textAppearance="@style/SubHead2_bld14"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/cell_padding"
                android:text="@{item.name}"
                tools:text="Notification Category Preference" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/switchSettingsDescription"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Body_12"
                android:textColor="@color/gray200"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/cell_padding"
                android:text="@{item.description}"
                tools:text="Notification Category Preference" />

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

        <com.google.android.material.materialswitch.MaterialSwitch
                    android:id="@+id/settingsSwitch"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/cell_padding"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
                    android:checked="@{item.enabled}"
                    style="@style/SwitchStyle"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and the `SwitchStyle` is defined as below:

```
    <style name="SwitchStyle" parent="Widget.Material3.CompoundButton.MaterialSwitch">
        <item name="android:thumb">@drawable/switch_thumb</item>
        <item name="thumbTint">@color/white</item>
        <item name="track">@drawable/custom_track</item>
        <item name="trackTint">@color/switch_selector</item>
        <item name="android:background">@null</item>
    </style>
```

switch_thumb.xml

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="28dp"
    android:height="28dp"
    android:viewportWidth="28"
    android:viewportHeight="28">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:pathData="M14,14m-14,0a14,14 0,1 1,28 0a14,14 0,1 1,-28 0" />
</vector>
```

custom_track.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size android:height="32dp" android:width="60dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/green300" />
            <corners android:radius="14dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="false">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size android:height="32dp" android:width="60dp" />
            <corners android:radius="14dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

and also the `switch_selector`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/green300" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/lightness200" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

Any idea how to prevent this ratio change and also not having the thumb bigger ?